# Events are not showing in search results WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom site that uses The Events Calendar to manage Events. I have a search in my main nav and I am unable to show events, only posts and pages. I have added custom filters but I know I am just overlooking something.

Here are the functions found in my theme's function.php

```
add_theme_support('html5' ,array('search-form'));
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'add_search_form', 10, 2);

function add_search_form($items, $args) {
          if( $args->theme_location == 'menu-top' )
          $items .= '<li class="search"><form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="'.home_url( '/' ).'">
          <input type="search" class="search-box" placeholder="Type Here"  name="s" />
          <input class="search-button" type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. __('Search') .'" /></form>
          </li>';
     return $items;
}

//Define what post types to include in search
function include_in_search( $query ) {
        if ( $query->is_search ) {
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'post', 'page', 'feed', 'tribe_events' ));
        }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('the_search_query', 'include_in_search' );
```

I sure would appreciate a hand in this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You're confusing `the_search_query` with `pre_get_posts`.

`the_search_query` allows you to modify a search string before display whereas `pre_get_posts` allows you to modify the query being performed.

Change this:

```
add_filter('the_search_query', 'include_in_search' );
```

To this:

```
add_filter( 'pre_get_posts', 'include_in_search' );
```

Also be sure you're only acting on the query in the right place. Add more conditionals to check you're not in the admin and you're operating on the main query.

Change this:

```
if ( $query->is_search ) {
```

To this:

```
if ( ! is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search() ) {
```